# What do the jQuery AJAX with Rails parameters mean?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know that for ajax you use :

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/home/index',
  data: {params1: "", params2: ""},
  success: function(response) {
    // code to be executed
  }
});
```

but what are the data params, and the function response. Ive looked everywhere and cant find an exact usage for rails

Comment: [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object. What params you app accepts and what response it returns is totally up to you. There is no exact usage - `jQuery.ajax` is a generic tool to perform ajax requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is not specific to rails because other frameworks can also use ajax as it is part of javascript.

The `data` that you passed in are params that you can access within the rails controller via `params[:arg1]`. The key will be the name of the symbol you should use to index into the `params` object.

The `function(response)` can be considered the payload the controller action is returning. Here's an example:

```
def index
  if params[:name].present?
    @users = User.where("name LIKE ?", params[:name]) #see symbol name
  else
    @users = User.all
  end

  render json: @user #something along these lines
end
```

And then in your ajax call, you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users',
  data: {name: "bobby"}, // see key name
  success: function(response) { // response here would be the returned users
  // code to be executed
  }
});
```